# G Suite API create groups

Tags: google-app-maker

I am just starting to work with app maker and I was wondering if it is possible to access g suite's api to create groups, emails, and folder directories in drive, all from information a user inputs in to a form on the app?

I am seeing a lot of documentation on GET for these but not POST.

Comment: Have you consulted the documentation? [This page in particular](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups) seems to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

[Drive create folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFolder(String))

[Drive create folder (Advanced)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder)

---

[Send Email](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))

[Send Email (Gmail)](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send)

---

[Create Group](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups#create_group) <- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-groups-settings

---

To trigger these server-side APIs you need to use [google.script.run.yourServeSideFunction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run). And you can find instructions how to enable Advanced Apps Script services in App Maker [here](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/settings#advanced_google_services).